# cant get past the error: "mkdir: Cannot create directory /user/hadoop. Name node is in safe mode."

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mkdir

I've installed hadoop version 2.7.2 on 64 bit CentOS 7. I can't seem to get past this:

```
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode.

$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

Safe mode is OFF

$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode.
```

I've looked at various posts online and nothing has hepled me so far.

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked that post and it does not give a solution to the actual problem where the error does not clear itself.

Comment: Is your datanodes running?

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge of Hadoop. This is the output I get:hdfs dfsadmin -report
Safe mode is ON
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------

Comment: I ended up creating a new VM and things now seem to work.